# How to Select any other button in Bottom navigation bar instead of first by Default

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm creating android app which contain bottom navigation bar with 4 buttons. I would like to Preselect the 3rd button when initially app is launches rather then the First tab by which is selected by Default. I have used replace frgment to load Third Fragment initially with below code

```
secondFragment = new second();
        replaceFragment(secondFragment);
```

But still, the first tab is active by default instead of the third although third fragment loads successfully

Here is the xml file from menu

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item

        android:id="@+id/bottom_action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_24dp"
        android:title="I"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_action_notif"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_24dp"
        android:title="II"
        android:checked="true"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_action_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_24dp"
        android:title="III"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_action_chat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_24dp"
        android:title="IV"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
</menu>
```

and activity xml file is

```html
       <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/mainBottomNav"
            android:background="@color/colorblog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

and my java file is

```html
  mainbottomNav = findViewById(R.id.mainBottomNav);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(mainbottomNav);//disable BottomNavigationView shift mode
        // FRAGMENTS
        mainbottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.bottom_action_home:
                        
                        return true;

                    case R.id.bottom_action_notif:
                        
                        return true;


                    case R.id.bottom_action_account:
                        
                        return true;



                    case R.id.bottom_action_chat:
                      
                    default:
                        return false;


                }
            }
        });
```

I would like to have Third Button active when application is launched i.e `case R.id.bottom_action_account:`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your code

```
  mainbottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.bottom_action_account);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that part of your navigation bar to be highlighted then use as mayank said:

```
navBar.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menuItem);
```

but if you're talking about when the activity starts, either change your setContentView to the correct activity, or use setActivity to complete change to a new intent/class.

Answer (score 0):

In your Java file, you can add code that looks like so:

```
  mainBottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.bottom_action_account);
```

You can add this to your onCreate at the end so that way it is made after the view is made so the end-user will see the third tab selected.

Cheers.